# NSIS ExecWait not launching secondary installer

Tags: nsis

I have a basic NSIS installer that is supposed to call a secondary - non-NSIS installer like so:

```
Section "Install First" SEC01
    File "WindowsPathToFile\setup.exe"
    DetailPrint "Installing the first Thing"
    ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\setup.exe"'
SectionEnd
```

NSIS and the installer do not throw any errors - however the sub installer is never launched or executed (and the application is never installed).

Note that if I put the call to "setup.exe" in a batch script and launch the batch script this does work. I was just hoping for something more elegant (that doesn't display the command prompt) as I'll have several custom installers that need to be called.

I didn't think that the ExecWait chain issue detailed in "[ExecWait Doesn't Wait](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/When_I_use_ExecWait,_it_doesn't_wait)" would affect me as I don't think my (setup.exe) installer is extracting a secondary installer.

The setup.exe installer is created by LabVIEW and I haven't found good information on what it's doing behind the scenes.

Am I missing something here? Or do I just need to stick with the batch script?

Answer (score 0):

Does the secondary installer require elevation? Do you have `RequestExecutionLevel admin` in your .nsi?

`ExecWait` internally calls the `CreateProcess` Windows API function and it will fail if the child process needs to be elevated by UAC.

If you are going to execute a child process that requires elevation then it is generally recommended that your installer requires elevation as well. If you for some reason don't want to do this then you can use [ShellExecWait](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellExecWait) or [${StdUtils.ExecShellWaitEx}](http://muldersoft.com/docs/stdutils_readme.html).

Comment: My secondary installer does require elevation. 

I found the first error:
I was using **RequestExecutionLevel user** instead of **admin** when I changed this I now have a new issue: 

When the NSIS installer calls the new installer it errors with:

**.\ConfigInfo.cpp(3266): InstallerError 11005
Fatal Error. Unable to find initialization file.
File C:\setup.ini not found.**

I suspect this is a path issue but at least now it seems to be doing something ...

Thank you for the help.